# How can I pass hasOne relationship data from laravel controller to Vue frontend

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to make a blog like app using Laravel and Vue but got stuck at a point. While developing the admin panel, I wanted a "Assign role" feature there where the admin can assign a user with particular role like "Admin, Moderator or Author"
For that, I defined a relationship in User model

```
public function role() {
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

Now in Vue, I want to display a table with all user names with their Roles besides them. For that, I sent a request to laravel server to fetch all data from Users table, the users table have the fields below

id , name, role_id , email , password, created_at, updated_at

I have a relationship defined in the Role model aswell

```
public function Users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Now when I fetch all users, I do

```
$users = User::all();
return $users;
```

How can I get the Role name inside my table, from the data i sent above.
Right now, I am only getting the role_id that is 1,2 or 3 but I want the names of the roles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I said this comment elsewhere but i'm not sure you've done it: `public function role() {     return $this->belongsTo(Role::class); }` You used the wrong relationship type

Comment: @TKoL, why should I not use hasOne here? Doesnt it make more sense that User "HAS ONE" role ?

Comment: No the thing is there is one to many relation bw Role and User. So each user belongsTo a particular role, and a role has many users. hasOne is used for one to one relationship.

Comment: 'belongsTo' vs 'hasOne' depends on which one has a column for the id of the other one. 'belongsTo' when the model you're in, Users, contains a column for the id of the model you're relating to, Roles. 'hasOne' if the Roles table had a column for user_id, which you can see in the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your relation.

User Model

```
public function role(){
   return $this->belongsTo(App\Role::class, 'role_id', 'id')
}
```

You can use the role relation and get the name from there.

```
// Eager load the relation
$users = User::with('role')->get();
return $users;
```

In your html.

```
$user->role->name;
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `roles`.`user_id` in (1))

Comment: You need to change your relation. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of your relationships is wrong for starters, should be

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

To minimize database queries do this:

```
$users = User::with('role)->get();
```

Now you can do something like

```
$users->toJson()
```

if you want to pass all the data to a javascript.

Or you can do

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->role->name }}
@endforeach
```

The important thing is that the `with` statement loads all the relationships in advance and so only one database query is executed.

Answer (score -1):

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->role;
}
return $users;
```

Believe it or not, that's all you need to do to populate the relationship inside any generated JSON. You just have to call the "magic method"

Comment: but you are not returning the role? does it work just like this?

Comment: You're returning the user object, just like before, and now it will be accessible as `user.role` -- the entire role object connected to the user will be inside there, for each user, in your javascript

Comment: I've had exactly this problem many times and I'm absolutely certain that this works.

Comment: it throws an error saying SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `roles`.`user_id` = 1 and `roles`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)"

Comment: Your relationship is wrong. Rather than 'hasOne', it should be 'belongsTo'. `public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}`